# Symfony: DQL select between date

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony

I'm trying to select from my SQLite table all the rows in selected months and sum the value in "total" column.

Here is my example table:

```
| ID |    DATE    | TOTAL |
|  1 | 22-11-2017 |  700  |
|  2 | 26-11-2017 |  100  |
|  3 | 28-11-2017 |  150  |
|  4 | 30-11-2017 |   50  |
```

Here is the dql function

```
public function getDataByMonth($repo, $year, $month)
{
date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01 00:00");
$dateEnd = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-31 23:59");
$query = $qb->where('b.date BETWEEN :start AND :end')
            ->setParameter('start', $date->format('d-m-Y H:i'))
            ->setParameter('end', $dateEnd->format('d-m-Y H:i'))
            ->select('SUM(b.total) as totals');
}
```

Even if the query goes, when I set `$month`variable to October (so 10) the query return `1000`instead of `NULL`.

I'm calling the function using

```
$earnings = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Invoices::class);
$this->getDataByMonth($earnings,date("Y"), strftime("%m", strtotime("-1 months")));
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I need to select the right rows relating to the selected month.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try sth like this, had similar problem and it worked:

```
->add('where', $qb->expr()->between(
        'e.datetimefield',
        ':from',
        ':to'
    ))
```

it's database software independent, should work with most databases, more info in doctrine documentation: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

and also don't format datetime object, ex:

```
$from = new \DateTime();
->setParameter('from', $from);
```

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values
>   --https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

So I don't think you can use BETWEEN.
I had similar issue with SQLite I ended up using timestamp

Comment: So should I change the field type to timestamp? Does Symfony handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 3 ?

```
$date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01 00:00");
$dateEnd = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-31 23:59");

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT SUM(p.total) FROM AppBundle:Invoices p WHERE  p.date >= :dateFirstDay and p.date <= :dateLastDay")
                ->setParameter('dateFirstDay',$date->format('d-m-Y H:i'))
                ->setParameter('dateLastDay',$dateEnd->format('d-m-Y H:i'));
```